# Applying Normals/Textures to Animated PNG (No Grease Pencil)

Tags: animation, texturing, import, normals, 2d

I want to import a 2d animation in PNG format but also want to utilize normal maps and such to my 2d animation to give it a certain look. I have the frames at the ready but don't know exactly how to get it working as a plane since Grease Pencil doesn't allow using textures. (Which is why I'm using the plane method for my texturing needs.) How would I go about doing this? (I am kinda new to the blender based 2d animation and am a novice, so I will be grateful for any help you can provide.)

Comment: Search for Animated Texture tutorial ... simply add node Texture > Image Sequence into your Shader (material node tree) ... your png files has to be be named by sequential numbering.